# Can't compile with static constexpr under pre-C++17 mode

Tags: c++, language-lawyer, c++17, constexpr

Why doesn't the following minimal example compile with `c++11` nor `c++14`, but compiles in `c++17` and `c++2a`?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <limits>
#include <vector>

// works:
// static constexpr int VALUE_LIMIT_A = std::numeric_limits<int>::max();

class Classy {
    // does not work in c++11 (constexpr introduced) nor c++14:
    // works if c++17 or newer:
    static constexpr int VALUE_LIMIT_A = std::numeric_limits<int>::max();
    int VALUE_LIMIT_B = std::numeric_limits<int>::max();

    public:
        explicit Classy();
        std::vector<int> classy;
};

Classy::Classy() {
    // does not work:
    classy.resize(3, VALUE_LIMIT_A);

    // works:
    // classy.resize(3, std::numeric_limits<int>::max());

    // works:
    // std::cout << VALUE_LIMIT_A;

    // works:
    // classy.resize(3, VALUE_LIMIT_B);
}

// required in c++11 and c++14
// constexpr int Classy::VALUE_LIMIT_A;

int main() {
    Classy classy{};

    for (const auto& elem : classy.classy) {
        std::cout << elem << ",";
    }
    std::cout << "\n";
}
```

Here is output with `c++11`:

```
$ g++ -std=c++11 main.cpp && ./a.out
/tmp/ccon7pPo.o: In function `Classy::Classy()':
main.cpp:(.text+0x31): undefined reference to `Classy::VALUE_LIMIT_A'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Here is output with `c++17`:

```
$ g++ -std=c++17 main.cpp && ./a.out
2147483647,2147483647,2147483647,
```

Comment: It's important to differentiate between _compiler_ errors and _linker_ errors. Your program succeeds in compiling - even on C++11. What it fails to do is link.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because since C++17, the definition of the constexpr [static data member](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/static#Constant_static_members) at namespace scope is not required again.

> If a const `non-inline (since C++17)` static data member `or a constexpr static data member (since C++11)` is [odr-used](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/definition#ODR-use), a definition
>   at namespace scope is still required, but it cannot have an
>   initializer. `This definition is deprecated for constexpr data members (since C++17).`
>
> ```
> struct X {
>     static const int n = 1;
>     static constexpr int m = 4;
> };
> const int *p = &X::n, *q = &X::m; // X::n and X::m are odr-used
> const int X::n;             // … so a definition is necessary
> constexpr int X::m;         // … (except for X::m in C++17)
> ```
>
> If a static data member is declared `constexpr`, it is implicitly `inline`
>   and does not need to be redeclared at namespace scope. This
>   redeclaration without an initializer (formerly required as shown
>   above) is still permitted, but is deprecated. (since C++17)

And note that [`std::vector::resize`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/resize) takes the 2nd parameter by reference; which cause `VALUE_LIMIT_A` to be [odr-used](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/definition#ODR-use) for `classy.resize(3, VALUE_LIMIT_A);`.

Answer (score 4):

Since C++17, with the introduction of inline variables, `static constexpr` data members are implicitly inline variables:

> **[dcl.constexpr]**
>
> [1](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/dcl.constexpr#1) ... A function or static data member declared with the constexpr
>   specifier is implicitly an inline function or variable
>   ([dcl.inline])...

Inline variables, like inline functions, are defined in every translation units they are used in. And the compiler resolves the multiple definitions into a single one. This means, the unlike C++14, there is no need to explicitly provide an out of class definition for a `static constexpr` variable for the sake of the ODR, the compiler takes care of it.

You can also get away with it in C++14, too. Like the other answer mentions, it is `resize` that ODR-uses the static data member. You can work around it, though:

```
classy.resize(3, int(VALUE_LIMIT_A));
```

While it looks superfluous, it in fact has different behavior to using the constant directly. This creates an integer temporary, with the *value* of the constant. But it doesn't ODR-use the constant. The temporary is bound to the reference instead, and so the problem is avoided. While it's better to define the constant in pre-C++17 code, you can use this trick to adapt code you have no control over.